# Sql Server 2005 Express Edition Question

Tags: sql-server-2005

We have a Sql Server 2005 Standard Edition running on a Production website. We'd like to  move to a cloud hosting but they only offer Sql Server Express Edition on there.

My question is, will there be any problems in moving over? We only use tables, views, stored procedures and a few user defined functions. And we also have a Backup Maintenance Plan in place. Will any if this change?

WHat other limitations/problems (if any) can we expect to have? And is it a good idea to run on Express in Production?

And I would like to add, will it be OK if we moved from SQL server 2005 Standard to Sql Server 2008 Express - what possible problems there could be with this move?

Comment: Not programming related, so will probably get closed soon.

Comment: I think the question has merit - when programming using SQL Server, it's important to know the limitations of the edition you are using, or potentially going to be using in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limitations for SQL Server 2005 Express as listed [here](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx)

These include:
- max 1GB RAM only
- max DB size of 4GB
- 1 CPU

Theses restrictions may cause you a problem. See the full list in the link.

With regrd to moving from 2005 Standard, to 2008 Express, then I expect the limitations of Express Edition may be the main factor when you consider if it really is an option. The limitations for 2008 Express are similar, see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx).

Hope this helps

Comment: We already have only 1 CPU and 2GB of RAM allowance on the OS. Not sure how much the Standard version uses. And a DB size of 4GB is OK for our requirements I guess. Would the memory from 2GB to 1 GB cause a substantial hit in performance?

Comment: Re: RAM - hard to say without knowing what your environment is like, how hard the DB gets hit. But in my experience, the more RAM you have the better!

Comment: I think the question is, how much does our standard version uses right now . The OS memory is 2GB, does our standard version uses all of it ? If not, then moving to Express would be the same as it is now.

Comment: Have a look in Task Manager to see what you're currently using (check when the DB is actually being used). SQL Server will use as much as it can, and will only release memory when it has to (i.e. the OS needs it). 2GB RAM in the machine won't actually mean there's a great deal available for SQL Server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The migration im unsure.

Express does not support triggers (fully), nor SQL scheudling.

Its size is limited to 4GB.

You can only ever have one instance with express.

It does however support Full Text and Reporting Services (in the express advanced edition)

We have plenty of clients running SQL Express due to cost. Only small pain has been the need to write a windows service for a job that could be easily run in proper SQL scheduling in the paid for the version.

Im sure there are many more differences but these are the ones im aware of, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Jammin. I will keep these in mind. We only need one instance so thats not a problem. And yes, it looks like the scheduled backups are going to be an issue.

Comment: To be honest Jimmy, im unsure the deal with scheduled backups on express and this should be something your provider can do. I meant scheduled tasks, eg doing things every day to your data @1am, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

I've used SQL Server Express for simple data persistence in production with no issues.

From the looks of your situation the only feature that will not be supported is backup maintenance. However, if you're hosted on a cloud, your ISP should take care of backup for you.

Comment: Yes I did figure out that backup wouldnt be supported. I am going to ask this question to hosting now, about backups. Thanks for the advice.